# jQuery - Iterating a API command over several objects but via unique ID?

Tags: jquery, iteration, getelementbyid, vimeo

I have a stack of vimeos on a page, I want to make them all mute though as they will be playing simultaneously.

I've got it working on only one vimeo. As it needs the unique ID for each vimeo.
But I'm not interested in doing different things to the videos. I just want to give them one rule, and obviously not have to write it out each time I upload a new vimeo.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("player_1");
iframe.api("api_setVolume", 50);
```

I tried making all the vimeo's ID = player_1, but that doesn't work.
For some reason there's no getElementByClass in JS, there should be no? It'd be useful for things like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the [testpage](http://marckremers.com/fuckvimeo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is tagged jQuery, I'll give you a solution that *should* work for that, though I haven't tried messing with iframe classes.

Add `class="vimeo"` to the iframes.  Iterate through them with the following:

```
$(".vimeo").each(function() {
    this.api("api_setVolume",50);
});
```

`each` will iterate through all the elements that are matched by the selector (in this case, `vimeo`).

**EDIT**

Since jQuery doesn't seem to like messing with iframes, there's a more programmatic way of doing what's already working for you:

```
var player_count = 2;
for (var i = 1; i < player_count+1; i++) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("player_" + i);
    iframe.api("api_setVolume", 50);
    //put other global rules here...
}
```

The trick now is determining what `player_count` should be.

Comment: Hmm I guess jQuery does not like iFrames... even if i replace the api call with "css("visibility","hidden");" for example, it doesnt do anything to it... Might there be another way?

Comment: (You can see what i mean in the original link)

Comment: You beat me to it (re:answering my new question!)

Comment: i'll try this out, i guess I could get the count by counting amount of posts in the vimeo category

Comment: Just edited, had an off-by-one error.  The old version would start looking for `player_0` instead of `player_1`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will let you select a set of elements by class with the syntax: $(".myClass")

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/